# I want to add a value to a list and do some stuff with it

Tags: python, list

so I have an entry where you can enter text. it should then be converted into an integer so it can be placed inside a list.SOmething went wrong and I can't find the problem.Thanks in advance

```
my_list.append(try:
        int(entry.get())
                   except:
        fail_message = tk.Label (frame, height=6, text = "something went wrong", )
        fail_message.pack(side= tk.LEFT))
```

Comment: try and except should be outside of the append

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
    try:
        my_list.append(int(entry.get()))
    except:
        fail_message = tk.Label (frame, height=6, text = "something went wrong", )
        fail_message.pack(side= tk.LEFT)
```